# Fieldset values displaying in profile page but if another person registered it showing error in profile page -django

Tags: python, django

I have member table for registered persons. I want to display that member table values of particular person in profile page who is logged in. I used Member.objects.get() data is displaying in the profile page of the person who is logged in. but if another person registered it showing error in profile page like.

this is my error

```
    MultipleObjectsReturned at /web/profile/
    get() returned more than one Member -- it returned 2!
```

this is my `views.py`

```py
    def profile(request):
        member = Member.objects.get()
        print(member.Email)
        return render(request, 'web/profile.html',{'member':member} )
```

here is my member model.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
  fullname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
  companyname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
  Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   password=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   contactno = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='anything')
```

Comment: `Member.objects.get()` method required to be filtered like `Member.objects.get(name='something')`

Answer (score 0):

`get()` is supposed to return only one object, thus you need to filter it in order to make the returned object unique.

Also, to make sure your user is authenticated, use `@login_required`.

Assuming your Member model has a ForeignKeyField with the User, and you want to filter Member so it matches the current logged in user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profile(request):
    member = Member.objects.get(user=request.user)
    print(member.Email)
    return render(request, 'web/profile.html',{'member':member} )
```

Comment: Can you add the Member model in your question ?

Comment: i had updated everything can you please check , please  give me solution

Comment: None of your field in your Model is unique... so it's quite a problem if you're trying to retrieve one (and only one) instance of Member. In order to use get(), you want to filter the Member model in order to finally get only one member... I don't know your business model so i can't help you much more... Maybe `Member.objects.get(email="something")` would make it but still you'd need to add unique=True in your email field.